# Why is php session data not saved when I post data at almost the same time an ajax get request is executed?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

Using a html element for search, my search allows GET and POST requests. I am sending the pressed keys using ajax GET for live search (timeout 750ms) and when the form is submitted, the string is POSTED.

The problem is that new session data is not saved when the ajax request and the form is submitted at the same time.

I found two solutions to this problem but they seem to mask the real problem. First solution is to stop the ajax request when enter is pressed using javascript `if ((event.keyCode || event.which) == 13)` and 2nd solution is calling `session_write_close()` and `session_start()` right after new session data is saved.

Can you explain why some session data is not saved (while others are properly saved during same request) when ajax GET is executed while a html form is in the middle of being posted or else explain the need for calling session_write_close and session_start to make sure session data is saved during critical operations like checking CSRF: generate new token if post is valid and save this in session?

Example code:

PHP Wrapper for storing new key:

```
public function setCsrfKey($property)
{
    $_SESSION['x']['CsrfKey'] = (string) $property; 
}
```

JS code:

```
$(searchBox).on("keyup", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    clearTimeout(ajaxTimeOut);

    var keyPressed = e.keyCode || e.which;

    var string = $(this).val();

    if (string.length < 3) {
        queueList.clearQueue('ajaxCall');

        return;
    }

    queueList.queue('ajaxCall', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: urlString,
            type: 'GET',
        }).done (function( data ) {
        }).fail (function(){
        });
    });

    ajaxTimeOut = setTimeout( function(){
        while (queueList.queue('ajaxCall').length > 1) {
            queueList.queue('ajaxCall').shift();
        }
        queueList.dequeue('ajaxCall');
    }, 750);

});
```

Comment: Could you show us some revelent code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP writes session data when the script ends unless you tell it otherwise (with `session_write_close`). What happens with two simultaneous requests in the same session depends on your session handler...but if the request is allowed to happen, the two requests typically won't see each other's changes to the session, and one's changes will generally get lost.

Calling `session_write_close` saves the session so that future requests will use the updated session. It's a bit of a hack; what you have here is a race condition, and there's still a chance of stuff breaking. It'll just be a lot lower the sooner you can commit your changes to the disk/database/whatever. Lower still if you can insert a short delay between requests as well.

Of course, once you've closed the session, it won't get saved when the script ends, so nothing else will get added to it. You have to call `session_start()` to reopen it if you want to make further changes to it.

Comment: Ok, but the GET request does not cause any changes to any session variable. Only the POST request generates a new key and saves this in session. But when both requests are send, no changes are saved. However, $_SESSION['test'] = date('H:i:s:') in the constructor function of my session wrapper is always saved.

Comment: @Nitin: PHP doesn't track whether session data has been modified, IIRC -- meaning even the GET request, if it opens the session, causes a write when the request is done. If the session has been changed by another request in the meantime, those changes will get lost.

Comment: Ahh, ok, that explains why stopping the get request does not cause this problem but how does session_write_close() and immediatly adding session_start() allow both requests to execute without losing any data? And some changes are always saved at the same time the new CSRF key is not saved?

Comment: Closing the session triggers a write, so the next request sees the changes you made. There's still a chance of losing data (like i said, you have a race condition going on here...no guarantees about what will happen), but the chance is lower the sooner you close the session. You don't have to reopen it (and really, you shouldn't) unless you need to make further changes that you want to be saved.

Comment: Ok, just tried upping the delay of ajax request from 750ms to 2000ms and the requests work fine in line with your explanations (race conditions). Interesting. Thank you!